# Is std::variant allowed to allocate memory for its members?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, c++17, variant

I was wondering if an implementation of `std::variant` must necessarily be "flat" or whether it is allowed to dynamically allocate memory for its members, such that a sequence of variants would degenerate to a sequence of pointers, thereby destroying cache locality.

Comment: I added the word "flat" to the title as I initially searched for exactly that. I will put it in the question body, so it is searchable, while keeping the more descriptive title you proposed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, very explicitly. From [[variant.variant]](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#variant-1):

> Any instance of `variant` at any given time either holds a value of one of its alternative types, or it holds no value. When an instance of `variant` holds a value of alternative type `T`, it means that a value of type `T`, referred to as the variant object's *contained* value, is allocated within the storage of the `variant` object. **Implementations are not permitted to use additional storage, such as dynamic memory, to allocate the contained value.** The contained value shall be allocated in a region of the `variant` storage suitably aligned for all types in `Types...`. It is implementation-defined whether over-aligned types are supported.

Comment: Does that mean that a variant of vectors (for example) is not allowed?  GCC and MSVC appear to accept this, but Clang does not: https://godbolt.org/g/ZZAXor

Comment: @0x5453 Uh, no? It's definitely allowed. Such a restriction wouldn't make any sense, nor be enforceable. Clang rejects it because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46506387/2069064).

Comment: Right, that makes sense now that I re-read the wording of the standard.  Thanks.

Comment: The variant containing the vector isn't doing any dynamic allocation, the vector is. It's no different from having a pointer type in a variant -- you're allowed to store a pointer to dynamic memory there. @0x5453

Comment: @Barry: I'm actually quite surprised the standard contains such an explicit statement about this behavior. After all, `tuple` doesn't have similar wording, despite the fact that there's basically no implementation of it that would dynamically allocate storage for the members.

Comment: @Nicol True. I guess it's strongly implied by being am extension of the`pair`.

Comment: @NicolBolas FWIW, `tuple` does [require](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple#cnstr-2) *For each tuple constructor, an exception is thrown only if the construction of one of the types in Types throws an exception.*  AFAIK, that means it can't dynamically allocate.

Answer (score 9):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) `::std::variant` must not allocate dynamic memory.

> As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type T, **the
>   object representation of T is allocated directly within the object
>   representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to
>   allocate additional (dynamic) memory.**

Comment: I’m not sure if the question is useful, especially since answer doesn’t quote standard.

Comment: @Incomputable I strongly disagree. It is a very valid question with a very good answer. You don't need to always quote from standard.

Comment: @bolov, my opinion is that if it is possible to find it in one google search, it is not worth separate question and answer. Decrypting standard is quite hard though. I upvoted the new answer, and left the question intact. May be SO taught me too hard about searching on my own, dunno.

Comment: @Incomputable an answer found somewhere on google does not add value to this community content in any way. I don't care if you can find the answer with google. If it is a good question, I want it here, on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Incomputable if you can find the answer with google and that answer is already on stackoverflow, well, that is an entire other problem....

Comment: @bolov, if it is better documented somewhere else, then it shouldn’t be brought here. I believe it is written somewhere in the help center.  But yeah, too much C++ questions are here, so maybe having them in one place is good.

Comment: I agree that I should have taken the answer directly from the standard, not cppreference. But I consider cppreference as good as the standard (and much easier to navigate).